# pandas DataFrame: Maximum and minimum values of the addition of the values of the same sign in the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame. The values of the DataFrame are the result of three calculation models (RSA1, RSA 2, RSA 3). Groups and cases are the same for each model. The values of the columns Fx, Fy, Fz can be either positive or negative floats.

```
    Model   Group   Case    Fx      Fy      Fz
0   RSA 1   G       100     120.0   0.0     140.0
1   RSA 1   G       101     40.0    140.0   50.0
2   RSA 1   Q       200     10.0    -50.0   30.0
3   RSA 1   Q       201     -50.0   -20.0   -60.0
4   RSA 1   WX      500     -80.0   -20.0   -40.0
5   RSA 1   WX      501     -10.0   -80.0   70.0
6   RSA 1   WY      600     90.0    -40.0   -10.0
7   RSA 1   WY      601     -80.0   80.0    -20.0
32  RSA 2   G       100     40.0    60.0    140.0
33  RSA 2   G       101     120.0   130.0   140.0
34  RSA 2   Q       200     -90.0   -70.0   -80.0
35  RSA 2   Q       201     50.0    0.0     -100.0
36  RSA 2   WX      500    -70.0    20.0    -20.0
37  RSA 2   WX      501     -50.0   60.0    40.0
38  RSA 2   WY      600    -80.0    90.0    -100.0
39  RSA 2   WY      601     30.0    -60.0   40.0
64  RSA 3   G       100     130.0   50.0    110.0
65  RSA 3   G       101     60.0    20.0    120.0
66  RSA 3   Q       200     0.0    -70.0    40.0
67  RSA 3   Q       201     -10.0   -30.0   -70.0
68  RSA 3   WX      500    -30.0    70.0    -40.0
69  RSA 3   WX      501     60.0    80.0    40.0
70  RSA 3   WY      600    -20.0    80.0    -100.0
71  RSA 3   WY      601     0.0     90.0    -30.0
```

I’m loking for:

1. Maximum and minimum values among all models of the addition of values of all cases in the same group. E. g.:

> Model: RSA 1; Group: G; Fx -> 120.0 + 40.0 = 160.0
>
> Model: RSA 2; Group: G; Fx -> 40.0 + 120.0 = 160.0
>
> Model: RSA 3; Group: G; Fx -> 130.0 + 60.0 = 190.0
>
> **max value: 190.0**
>
> **min value: 160.0**

2. Maximum and minimum values from all models of the values in each case. E. g.:

> Model: RSA 1; Group: G; Case 600; Fx -> 90.0
>
> Model: RSA 1; Group: G; Case 601; Fx -> -80.0
>
> Model: RSA 2; Group: G; Case 600; Fx -> -80.0
>
> Model: RSA 2; Group: G; Case 601; Fx -> 30.0
>
> Model: RSA 3; Group: G; Case 600; Fx -> -20.0
>
> Model: RSA 3; Group: G; Case 601; Fx -> 0.0
>
> **max value: 90.0**
>
> **min value: -80.0**

3. Maximum and minimum values from among all the models of the addition of values of the same sign of all the cases of the same group. E. g.:

> Model: RSA 1; Group: Q; Case 200; Fz -> 30.0
>
> Model: RSA 1; Group: Q; Case 201; Fz -> -60.0
>
> *Model: RSA 1; Group: Q; addition of positive values : 30.0*
>
> *Model: RSA 1; Group: Q; addition of negative values: -60.0*
>
> Model: RSA 2; Group: Q; Case 200; Fz -> -80.0
>
> Model: RSA 2; Group: Q; Case 201; Fz -> -100.0
>
> *Model: RSA 2; Group: Q; addition of positive values : 0.0*
>
> *Model: RSA 2; Group: Q; addition of negative values: -180.0*
>
> Model: RSA 3; Group: Q; Case 200; Fz -> 40.0
>
> Model: RSA 3; Group: Q; Case 201; Fz -> -70.0
>
> *Model: RSA 3; Group: Q; addition of positive values : 40.0*
>
> *Model: RSA 3; Group: Q; addition of negative values: -70.0*
>
> **max value: 40.0**
>
> **min value: -180.0**

This is the code for the first case:

```
df_1 = df.groupby(['Model', 'Group']).sum()
df_1.groupby('Group').agg(['max', 'min'])

        Fx              Fy              Fz
        max     min     max     min     max     min
Group                       
G       190.0   160.0   190.0   70.0    280.0   190.0
Q       -10.0   -40.0   -70.0   -100.0  -30.0   -180.0
WX      30.0    -120.0  150.0   -100.0  30.0    0.0
WY      10.0    -50.0   170.0   30.0    -30.0   -130.0
```

This is the code for the second case:

```
df_2 = df.groupby(['Model', 'Group', 'Case']).sum()
df_2.groupby('Group').agg(['max', 'min'])

        Fx              Fy              Fz
        max     min     max     min     max     min
Group                       
G       130.0   40.0    140.0   0.0     140.0   50.0
Q       50.0    -90.0   0.0    -70.0    40.0    -100.0
WX      60.0    -80.0   80.0    -80.0   70.0    -40.0
WY      90.0    -80.0   90.0    -60.0   40.0    -100.0
```

And I have a problem with the third case:

```
df_3 = df.groupby(['Model', 'Group', 'Case']).sum()
df_31 = df_3.groupby(['Model', 'Group']).agg([
    ('max', lambda x : x[x >= 0].sum()),
    ('min', lambda x : x[x < 0].sum())
    ])
df_31.groupby('Group').agg(['max', 'min'])

        Fx                              Fy                              Fz
        max             min             max             min             max             min
        max     min     max     min     max     min     max     min     max     min     max     min
Group                                               
G       190.0   160.0   0.0     0.0     190.0   70.0    0.0     0.0     280.0   190.0   0.0     0.0
Q       50.0    0.0     -10.0   -90.0   0.0     0.0     -70.0   -100.0  40.0    0.0     -60.0   -180.0
WX      60.0    0.0     -30.0   -120.0  150.0   0.0     0.0     -100.0  70.0    40.0    -20.0   -40.0
WY      90.0    0.0     -20.0   -80.0   170.0   80.0    0.0     -60.0   40.0    0.0     -30.0   -130.0
```

I can't get a DataFrame with the same format as the previous ones.

The results I'm looking for are in the max-max and min-min columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest split DataFrame for 2 subDataFrames and processing each separately for aggregate minimal and maximal and last join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with change levels by [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and sorting `MultiIndex`:

```
df_3 = df.groupby(['Model', 'Group', 'Case']).sum()
df_31 = df_3.groupby(['Model', 'Group']).agg([
    ('max', lambda x : x[x >= 0].sum()),
    ('min', lambda x : x[x < 0].sum())
    ])

df_311 = df_31.xs('max', axis=1, level=1).groupby('Group').max()
df_312 = df_31.xs('min', axis=1, level=1).groupby('Group').min()

df_31 = (pd.concat([df_311, df_312], axis=1, keys=('max','min'))
           .swaplevel(1,0, axis=1)
           .sort_index(axis=1))
print (df_31)
          Fx            Fy            Fz       
         max    min    max    min    max    min
Group                                          
G      190.0    0.0  190.0    0.0  280.0    0.0
Q       50.0  -90.0    0.0 -100.0   40.0 -180.0
WX      60.0 -120.0  150.0 -100.0   70.0  -40.0
WY      90.0  -80.0  170.0  -60.0   40.0 -130.0
```